# PHP OBJECT ORIENTED PROGRAMMING (OOP) DATE

Tags: php, date

So, I have this problem in PHP OOP that only the current date is being recorded in mySQL DATABASE rather than my own input date. what is wrong with my syntax.

```php
$this->datearrive = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->datearrive));

$this->datearrive = date('Y-m-d');

$stmt->bindParam(":datearrive",$this->datearrive);
```

Comment: `$this->datearrive = date('Y-m-d');`, this get the current date with a specific format. Yet the problem you have, is the one being recorded is the current date?

Comment: In line, $this->datearrive = date('Y-m-d');    date('Y-m-d') stores current date, that's why your third line saves current date

Comment: thank you guys for your info, what syntax/code should i use to input the date that i want?, im an absolute beginner in php  and php oop.

Comment: yes the current system date is being recorded not the one that i input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second parameter as a time source for `date()` or it will use your system time:

```
$this->datearrive = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->datearrive));
```

This is assuming, of course, that `$this->datearrive` contains the date you want saved.